# Nose-Hoover Barostat

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

Much can be found about the Nose-Hoover Thermostat. However I seem to be having difficulty finding out details about the Nose-Hoover Barostat, and how it is implemented.

Would anyone be able to give some general ideas on how it works? And further reading materials would be awesome too.